# How can I execute a external JS from HTML every 10 min?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HMTL which execute a external JS. The JS returns my Google Calender events. I want my calender to be **updated automatically every 10minutes.**

The HTML looks like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="format-google-calendar.js"></script>
<script>
  formatGoogleCalendar.init({
    calendarUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/magic.kfs@gmx.de/events?key=AIzaSyDei0zrhHPHAtYc5x7vjdUmGaC3FlFnm1Y ',
    past: true,
    upcoming: true,
    sameDayTimes: true,
    pastTopN: 20,
    upcomingTopN: 4,
    recurringEvents: true,
    itemsTagName: 'ul',
    upcomingSelector: '#events-upcoming',
    pastSelector: '#events-past',
    upcomingHeading: '<div id="Termine" >Kommende Termine</div> ',
    pastHeading: '<p><h2 class="medium left">Vergangene Termine</h2></p>',
    format: ['*date*', ': ', '*summary*', ' &mdash; ', '*description*', ' in ', '*location*']

  });
</script>
```

The JS looks like:

```
var formatGoogleCalendar = (function() {

'use strict';

var config;




//Gets JSON from Google Calendar and transfroms it into html list items and appends it to past or upcoming events list
var init = function(settings) {
    var result = [];

    config = settings;
    var finalURL = settings.calendarUrl;

    if(settings.recurringEvents) finalURL = finalURL.concat("&singleEvents=true");



    //Get JSON, parse it, transform into list items and append it to past or upcoming events list
    jQuery.getJSON(finalURL, function(data) {
        // Remove any cancelled events
        data.items.forEach(function removeCancelledEvents(item) {
            if (item && item.hasOwnProperty('status') && item.status !== 'cancelled') {
                result.push(item);
            }
        });

        result.sort(comp).reverse();

        var pastCounter = 0,
            upcomingCounter = 0,
            pastResult = [],
            upcomingResult = [],
            upcomingResultTemp = [],
            $upcomingElem = jQuery(settings.upcomingSelector),
            $pastElem = jQuery(settings.pastSelector),
            i;

        if (settings.pastTopN === -1) {
            settings.pastTopN = result.length;
        }

        if (settings.upcomingTopN === -1) {
            settings.upcomingTopN = result.length;
        }

        if (settings.past === false) {
            settings.pastTopN = 0;
        }

        if (settings.upcoming === false) {
            settings.upcomingTopN = 0;
        }

        for (i in result) {

            if (isPast(result[i].end.dateTime || result[i].end.date)) {
                if (pastCounter < settings.pastTopN) {
                   pastResult.push(result[i]);
                   pastCounter++;
                }
            } else {
                upcomingResultTemp.push(result[i]);
            }
        }

        upcomingResultTemp.reverse();

        for (i in upcomingResultTemp) {
            if (upcomingCounter < settings.upcomingTopN) {
                upcomingResult.push(upcomingResultTemp[i]);
                upcomingCounter++;
            }
        }

        for (i in pastResult) {
            $pastElem.append(transformationList(pastResult[i], settings.itemsTagName, settings.format));
        }

        for (i in upcomingResult) {
            $upcomingElem.append(transformationList(upcomingResult[i], settings.itemsTagName, settings.format));
        }

        if ($upcomingElem.children().length !== 0) {
            jQuery(settings.upcomingHeading).insertBefore($upcomingElem);
        }

        if ($pastElem.children().length !== 0) {
            jQuery(settings.pastHeading).insertBefore($pastElem);
        }

    });
};

//Compare dates
var comp = function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.start.dateTime || a.start.date).getTime() - new Date(b.start.dateTime || b.start.date).getTime();
};

//Overwrites defaultSettings values with overrideSettings and adds overrideSettings if non existent in defaultSettings
var mergeOptions = function(defaultSettings, overrideSettings){
    var newObject = {},
        i;
    for (i in defaultSettings) {
        newObject[i] = defaultSettings[i];
    }
    for (i in overrideSettings) {
        newObject[i] = overrideSettings[i];
    }
    return newObject;
};

var isAllDay = function (dateStart, dateEnd) {
  var dateStartFormatted = getDateFormatted(dateStart),
      dateEndFormatted = getDateFormatted(dateEnd);

  //if start date is midnight and the end date a following day midnight as well
  if ((dateStartFormatted.getTime() === dateEndFormatted.getTime() - 86400000) &&
      dateStartFormatted.getMinutes() === 0 &&
      dateStartFormatted.getHours() === 0) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};

//Get all necessary data (dates, location, summary, description) and creates a list item
var transformationList = function(result, tagName, format) {
    var dateStart = getDateInfo(result.start.dateTime || result.start.date),
        dateEnd = getDateInfo(result.end.dateTime || result.end.date),
        moreDaysEvent = (typeof result.end.date !== 'undefined'),
        dayNames = config.dayNames,
        isAllDayEvent = isAllDay(dateStart, dateEnd);

    if (moreDaysEvent) {
      dateStart = addOneDay(dateStart);
    }

    if (isAllDayEvent) {
      dateEnd = subtractOneMinute(dateEnd);
    }

    var dateFormatted = getFormattedDate(dateStart, dateEnd, moreDaysEvent, isAllDayEvent, dayNames),
        output = '<' + tagName + '>',
        summary = result.summary || '',
        description = result.description || '',
        location = result.location || '',
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < format.length; i++) {

        format[i] = format[i].toString();

        if (format[i] === '*summary*') {
            output = output.concat('<span class="summary">' + summary + '</span>');
        } else if (format[i] === '*date*') {
            output = output.concat('<span class="date">' + dateFormatted + '</span>');
        } else if (format[i] === '*description*') {
            output = output.concat('<span class="description">' + description + '</span>');
        } else if (format[i] === '*location*') {
            output = output.concat('<span class="location">' + location + '</span>');
        } else {
            if ((format[i + 1] === '*location*' && location !== '') ||
                (format[i + 1] === '*summary*' && summary !== '') ||
                (format[i + 1] === '*date*' && dateFormatted !== '') ||
                (format[i + 1] === '*description*' && description !== '')) {

                output = output.concat(format[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return output + '</' + tagName + '>';
};

//Check if date is later then now
var isPast = function(date) {
    var compareDate = new Date(date),
        now = new Date();

    if (now.getTime() > compareDate.getTime()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};

//Get temp array with information abou day in followin format: [day number, month number, year, hours, minutes]
var getDateInfo = function(date) {
    date = new Date(date);
    return [date.getDate(), date.getMonth(), date.getFullYear(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), 0, 0];
};

//Get month name according to index
var getMonthName = function (month) {
    var monthNames = [
        'Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli',               
'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'
    ];

    return monthNames[month];
};

var getDayName = function (day) {
  var dayNames = [
      'Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'
  ];

  return dayNames[day];
};

var getDayNameFormatted = function (dateFormatted) {
  return getDayName(getDateFormatted(dateFormatted).getDay()) + ' ';
};

var getDateFormatted = function (dateInfo) {
  return new Date(dateInfo[2], dateInfo[1], dateInfo[0], dateInfo[3], dateInfo[4] + 0, 0);
};

//Add one day
var addOneDay = function (dateInfo) {
 var date = getDateFormatted(dateInfo);
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + 86400000);
 return getDateInfo(date);
 };

//Subtract one day
var subtractOneDay = function (dateInfo) {
  var date = getDateFormatted(dateInfo);
  date.setTime(date.getTime() - 86400000);
  return getDateInfo(date);
};

//Subtract one minute
var subtractOneMinute = function (dateInfo) {
  var date = getDateFormatted(dateInfo);
  date.setTime(date.getTime() - 60000);
  return getDateInfo(date);
};

//Transformations for formatting date into human readable format
var formatDateSameDay = function(dateStart, dateEnd, moreDaysEvent, isAllDayEvent, dayNames) {
    var formattedTime = '',
        dayNameStart = '';

    if (dayNames) {
      dayNameStart = getDayNameFormatted(dateStart);
    }

    if (config.sameDayTimes && !moreDaysEvent && !isAllDayEvent) {
        formattedTime = ' from ' + getFormattedTime(dateStart) + ' - ' + getFormattedTime(dateEnd);
    }

    //month day, year time-time
    return dayNameStart + dateStart[0] + '. ' + getMonthName(dateStart[1]) +  ', ' + dateStart[2] + formattedTime;
};

var formatDateOneDay = function(dateStart, dayNames) {
  var dayName = '';

  if (dayNames) {
    dayName = getDayNameFormatted(dateStart);
  }
  //month day, year
   return dayName + dateStart[0] + '. ' + getMonthName(dateStart[1]) +  ', ' + dateStart[2];
};

var formatDateDifferentDay = function(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames) {
  var dayNameStart = '',
      dayNameEnd = '';

  if (dayNames) {
    dayNameStart = getDayNameFormatted(dateStart);
    dayNameEnd = getDayNameFormatted(dateEnd);
  }
    //month day-day, year
    return dayNameStart + getMonthName(dateStart[1]) + ' ' + dateStart[0] + '-' + dayNameEnd + dateEnd[0] + ', ' + dateStart[2];
};

var formatDateDifferentMonth = function(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames) {
  var dayNameStart = '',
      dayNameEnd = '';

  if (dayNames) {
    dayNameStart = getDayNameFormatted(dateStart);
    dayNameEnd = getDayNameFormatted(dateEnd);
  }
    //month day - month day, year
    return dayNameStart + dateStart[0] + '. ' + getMonthName(dateStart[1]) + ' ' + '-' + dayNameEnd + dateEnd[0] + '. ' + getMonthName(dateEnd[1]) + ', ' + dateStart[2];
};

var formatDateDifferentYear = function(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames) {
  var dayNameStart = '',
      dayNameEnd = '';

  if (dayNames) {
    dayNameStart = getDayNameFormatted(dateStart);
    dayNameEnd = getDayNameFormatted(dateEnd);
  }
    //month day, year - month day, year
   return dayNameStart + dateStart[0] + '. ' + getMonthName(dateStart[1])  + ', ' + dateStart[2] + '-' + dayNameEnd + dateEnd[0] + '. ' + getMonthName(dateEnd[1]) + ', ' + dateEnd[2];
};

//Check differences between dates and format them
var getFormattedDate = function(dateStart, dateEnd, moreDaysEvent, isAllDayEvent, dayNames) {
    var formattedDate = '';

    if (dateStart[0] === dateEnd[0]) {
        if (dateStart[1] === dateEnd[1]) {
            if (dateStart[2] === dateEnd[2]) {
                //month day, year
                formattedDate = formatDateSameDay(dateStart, dateEnd, moreDaysEvent, isAllDayEvent, dayNames);
            } else {
                //month day, year - month day, year
                formattedDate = formatDateDifferentYear(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames);
            }
        } else {
            if (dateStart[2] === dateEnd[2]) {
                //month day - month day, year
                formattedDate = formatDateDifferentMonth(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames);
            } else {
                //month day, year - month day, year
                formattedDate = formatDateDifferentYear(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (dateStart[1] === dateEnd[1]) {
            if (dateStart[2] === dateEnd[2]) {
                //month day-day, year
                formattedDate = formatDateDifferentDay(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames);
            } else {
                //month day, year - month day, year
                formattedDate = formatDateDifferentYear(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames);
            }
        } else {
            if (dateStart[2] === dateEnd[2]) {
                //month day - month day, year
                formattedDate = formatDateDifferentMonth(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames);
            } else {
                //month day, year - month day, year
                formattedDate = formatDateDifferentYear(dateStart, dateEnd, dayNames);
            }
        }
    }

    return formattedDate;
};

var getFormattedTime = function (date) {
   var formattedTime = '',
        period = 'Uhr',
        hour = date[3],
        minute = date[4];

    // Handle afternoon.
    if (hour >= 12) {
        period = 'Uhr';


    }

    // Handle midnight.
    if (hour === 0) {
        hour = 0;
    }

    // Ensure 2-digit minute value.
    minute = (minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + minute;

    // Format time.
    formattedTime = hour + ':' + minute + period;
    return formattedTime;
};

return {
    init: function (settingsOverride) {
        var settings = {
            calendarUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/milan.kacurak@gmail.com/events?key=AIzaSyCR3-ptjHE-_douJsn8o20oRwkxt-zHStY',
            past: true,
            upcoming: true,
            sameDayTimes: true,
            dayNames: true,
            pastTopN: -1,
            upcomingTopN: -1,
            recurringEvents: true,
            itemsTagName: 'li',
            upcomingSelector: '#events-upcoming',
            pastSelector: '#events-past',
            upcomingHeading: '<h2>Upcoming events</h2>',
            pastHeading: '<h2>Past events</h2>',
            format: ['*date*', ': ', '*summary*', ' &mdash; ', '*description*', ' in ', '*location*']
        };

        settings = mergeOptions(settings, settingsOverride);

        init(settings);
    }
};
 })();
```

Can you explain me based on my code how I can re-run the js every 10min? I am not sure where I have to put `setIntervall(?????????,10*60*1000)`?

Comment: Which function do you want to call in your interval? If you want to restart it try putting inside your interval the same `.init`function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put formatGoogleCalendar.init() in a setInterval, like this :

```
setInterval(function(){
formatGoogleCalendar.init({
    calendarUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/magic.kfs@gmx.de/events?key=AIzaSyDei0zrhHPHAtYc5x7vjdUmGaC3FlFnm1Y ',
    past: true,
    upcoming: true,
    sameDayTimes: true,
    pastTopN: 20,
    upcomingTopN: 4,
    recurringEvents: true,
    itemsTagName: 'ul',
    upcomingSelector: '#events-upcoming',
    pastSelector: '#events-past',
    upcomingHeading: '<div id="Termine" >Kommende Termine</div> ',
    pastHeading: '<p><h2 class="medium left">Vergangene Termine</h2></p>',
    format: ['*date*', ': ', '*summary*', ' &mdash; ', '*description*', ' in ', '*location*']

  });
}, 600000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your init into a function and call that function in the setInterval() every 10 minutes.

```
<script>
function calendarInit(){

  formatGoogleCalendar.init({
    calendarUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/magic.kfs@gmx.de/events?key=AIzaSyDei0zrhHPHAtYc5x7vjdUmGaC3FlFnm1Y ',
    past: true,
    upcoming: true,
    sameDayTimes: true,
    pastTopN: 20,
    upcomingTopN: 4,
    recurringEvents: true,
    itemsTagName: 'ul',
    upcomingSelector: '#events-upcoming',
    pastSelector: '#events-past',
    upcomingHeading: '<div id="Termine" >Kommende Termine</div> ',
    pastHeading: '<p><h2 class="medium left">Vergangene Termine</h2></p>',
    format: ['*date*', ': ', '*summary*', ' &mdash; ', '*description*', ' in ', '*location*']

  });
}

var cal = setInterval(calendarInit(), 10*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use

```
setInterval(function, delay)
```

delay is in milliseconds and function is the name of the function you want to call. Therefore, you need to wrap your content of js file within a function as

```
function callAgain()
{

var formatGoogleCalendar = (function() {
'use strict';
var config;
.
.
.

}
```

and then use the `setInterval(callAgain, 5000)` in the script part of your html file