# How can I refresh Google Calendar Events list without appending?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I'm using Milan Lund's excellent script https://www.milanlund.com/blog/javascript-library-google-calendar to retrieve my list of Google Calendar events. However, I'm trying to refresh the connection every 30 seconds so whenever someone lands on my page they see the current event.
I tried using the setInterval method as explained on this thread: [How can I execute a external JS from HTML every 10 min?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330972/how-can-i-execute-a-external-js-from-html-every-10-min) but this appends the result rather than replacing it (I need it to replace). Any suggestions please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me understand this.  Everytime one lands on your page your going to reload it every 30 seconds?  Have you considered that there is a quota to the number of requests you can make to the API per day? Why no thave a script running in the background checking and storing the information in a database and reading from that one request.

Comment: @DalmTo: I did wonder if there may be a problem making so many requests. I have seen a plugin which cache'd a daily list and then accessed that. Only problem was it wasn't compatible with v3 and did not pull in all events specified. Regarding your suggestion; if there are any changes made to the calendar during the same day, it would require the ability to update the cache'd list manually.

Comment: set up watch and you will be notified that there are changes for you to request.  https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push